# Why there is auto onBackPressed?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add feature, a very simple chat in my project android app using real time firebase database. The chat is working but if someone clicks send button after message is received in firebase the activity is automatically going to the previous activity.

```
  DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MyGroups").child("1234").child("chats");

        String message = messageTxt.getText().toString();
        String messageKey = ref.push().getKey();

        final String timeStamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

            HashMap<String,Object> messageInfoMap =new HashMap<>();
            messageInfoMap.put("senderName",username);
            messageInfoMap.put("senderId", mAuth.getUid());
            messageInfoMap.put("message",message);
            messageInfoMap.put("timeStamp", timeStamp);
            messageInfoMap.put("messageId", messageKey);
            ref.child(messageKey).updateChildren(messageInfoMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                    //Toast.makeText(GroupChat.this, "Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Activity is like auto onbackpressed after the message 'sent'

Comment: the relevant code will not help. please share logcat.

Comment: When your app crashes, your activity gets finished, just as if `onBackPressed()` was hit. Look in your logcat for an error message.

Comment: App does not crush, I want it to remain in the same activity after sending msg but it moves to previous actually (as if onbackpressed called)